# jQuery CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a beginner in javascript and jQuery, so please bear with me. I used the following code in jQuery to change the background of a div. But it is not working :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div1").click(function(){
    $(".div1").css("background","url"pic.png"");
  });
});
```

I cannot figure out the error. The function is working properly for

```
$(".div1").css("background","#000");
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's the extra `"` in here: `css("background","url"pic.png"")`. I'd assume you want something like `css("background","url('pic.png')")`

Comment: Sounds like you need [a text editor with automatic syntax coloring](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: @Ian I met cases where not using either quotes or double quontes in url() was failing.

Comment: @Virus721 I've never seen that happen, but at the same time I always include single quotes. Not sure why I didn't include in my comment, I'll edit

Comment: `$(".div1").css("background","url"pic.png"");` you have to escape the string in defining the value `"url"pic.png""` to be `"url(\"pic.png\")"` or use single quotation instead `"url('pic.png')"` and even you can use it without any quotations for css property `"url(pic.png)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with quotes. You used double quotes wrongly. You must use single quotes after a double quote has been used.
The code will be :-

```
$(".div1").css("background","url('smiley.gif')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(".div1").css("background","url"pic.png"");
```

to

```
$(".div1").css("background-image","url(pic.png)");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XdbTp/)**

Comment: Because your original answer included some form of using a `:`

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors. Try changing it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div1").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "url('pic.png')");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div1').css('background', "url('pic.png') left center no-repeat");
```

or to understand the [**.css() jquery method**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) in depth, try this:

```
$('.div1').css({
   'background-image' : 'url("pic.png")',
   'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
   'background-position' : 'left center'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**change:**

```
$(".div1").css("background","url"pic.png"");
```

**to:**

```
$(".div1").css("background","url('pic.png')");
```

*Note, using single/double quotes around your image path will prevent your CSS/Script from breaking if it happened to contain spaces.*

From the W3 spec:

> The format of a URI value is 'url(' followed by optional white space
>   followed by an optional single quote (') or double quote (") character
>   followed by the URI itself, followed by an optional single quote (')
>   or double quote (") character followed by optional white space
>   followed by ')'. The two quote characters must be the same.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri

Comment: Why would your image path contain spaces?

Comment: My point was that spaces shouldn't be in the URL. Properly encode the URL and it should be fine without quotes. I'd still suggest always using them and being consistent, but I don't see that as a major reason

Answer (score -2):

You have a syntax error:

```
 $(".div1").css("background","url"pic.png"");
```

Should be

```
$(".div1").css("background-image","url(pic.png)");
```

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don't understand the downvote for j08691's answer.  I think someone downvoted purely for fun.

Comment: Ohh...I didn't  downvote. I think people jump the gun sometimes. There could be small typos which can be corrected with a gentle nudge.